# static class property not working with Babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, jsdoc3

I am using JSDOC and all it supported npm plugins to create nice documentation. Getting hard time when jsdoc is running and parsing JSX file it always throws error as below near `=` sign

```
SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token
export default class SaveDesign extends Component {
 static displayName = 'SaveDesign';
}
```

conf.json file

```
{
  "source": {
    "include": [ "src/app/test.js", "src/app/components/Modals/Template/SaveDesign.jsx"],
    "exclude": [ "src/fonts", "src/icons", "src/less", "src/vector-icon" ],
    "includePattern": ".+\\.js(doc|x)?$",
    "excludePattern": "(^|\\/|\\\\)_"
  },
  "plugins": ["node_modules/jsdoc-babel"],
  "babel": {
    "extensions": ["js", "es6", "jsx"],
    "presets": ["es2015"]
  },
  "jsx": {
    "extensions": ["js", "jsx"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Class properties aren't part of the ES2015 spec, so they're not part of the ES2015 Babel preset either. [The proposal to add class properties to the language](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) is currently at Stage 3 of the standardization process, so you need the Stage 3 preset.

https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-3/

Alternatively, you could just install the class properties plugin on its own:

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties

Answer (score 4):

As stage-2 , stage-3 or any other stage preset are removed in babel 7 or newer so you have to add plugin separately. 
**Please use "require()" for importing plugin otherwise it wont work.**
Here is the .bablerc file -

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    [require("@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"), { loose: false }]
  ],
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

@Joe thanks yes the plugin which you mentioned will help to solve the problem. In my case the way I solved it was by making sure to have all .babelrc dependency copied to jsdoc babel property as well I was missing this piece which was giving me all the errors.